# Generate download path for generated files in Django

Tags: python, android, django, download

I have a Django server in which I generate files that I want to be downloaded to an Android app I'm also creating. Each of these files has an ID number, which the Android app will have. The android app will not know the name of the files. How can I generate download urls so that url is something like `mysite.com/download/"int id of file"/` and then my Android app will be able to download it via DownloadManager?

Below is the code that I want to use to accomplish that but any suggestions on other ways to accomplish this are welcome.

```
        String url = "customurl";

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle("Downloading");
        request.setDescription("Downloading new titles");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        if (downloadReference != 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What I ended up doing was adding an integer argument to the url I made for fetching songs:

`path('downloadsong/<int:pk>/', include('downloadsong.urls'))`

From there, I used the integer passed in to get the file path from my database and return it:

```
        #get mp3 file
        file_data = None
        with open(mp3Path, "rb") as f:
            file_data = f.read()

        #return file
        response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='audio/mpeg')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(os.path.basename(mp3Path))
        return response
```

And then the DownloadManager does its thing on the phone. Hope this helps someone in the future.